# Nautilus not auto refreshing contents of Windows share

Tags: linux, linux-mint, nautilus

I am using Nautilus on a Linux Mint 13 machine.  When connected to a windows share, I have to manually refresh the contents to pick up file changes.  Is there a way to make Nautilus auto-refresh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way for inotify to handle network filesystems so it won't work over NFS/SMB. Automatic refresh in Nautilus used to be done with [fam](http://oss.sgi.com/projects/fam/) (see also Alex Larsson's reply [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnome.nautilus/14296)) or [gamin](http://people.gnome.org/~veillard/gamin/index.html) (where you could [configure](http://people.gnome.org/~veillard/gamin/config.html) polling interval etc).

I think you could install/configure gamin and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've understood it, Nautilus uses *inotify* to detect file changes. Since Nautilus isn't showing the latest file changes...

> *When connected to a windows share...*

...I'm guessing that the amount of files on your windows share (combined with what *inotify* is already keeping track of) exceeds the maximum amount of files that *inotify* is allowed to watch.

I'd recommend that you try to increase the default value of *max_user_watches* for *inotify* to something like 100000 or more:

```
echo 100000 > /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

Comment: Ill give it a shot...  but were not talking about a large amount of files...  maybe a couple dozen

Comment: didnt work for me. :(